# Why 1st menu item selected by default at MenuAppBar

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

In this [menuAppBar](https://material-ui-next.com/demos/app-bar/#app-bar-with-menu) the first item in the menu is selected by default. Where in this [menu](https://material-ui-next.com/demos/menus/#menulist-composition) the first item is not selected by default, and that what I want is the same to be in the manuAppBar menu.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first example is implemented with the material-ui [Menu component](https://material-ui-next.com/api/menu/) and the second example is implemented using components from the [react-popper](https://github.com/souporserious/react-popper) library.

In the first example, the first item is highlighted because it has focus.  This is because Menu sets focus if it is open when mounted or updated.  Take a look at [the source](https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/blob/v1-beta/src/Menu/Menu.js):

```js
class Menu extends React.Component {
  componentDidMount() {
    if (this.props.open) {
      this.focus();
    }
  }

  componentDidUpdate(prevProps) {
    if (!prevProps.open && this.props.open) {
      // Needs to refocus as when a menu is rendered into another Modal,
      // the first modal might change the focus to prevent any leak.
      this.focus();
    }
  }
```

If you prefer react-popper and would like to use it in an [AppBar](https://material-ui-next.com/api/app-bar/), you can:

```js
<AppBar position="static">
  <Toolbar>
    <IconButton className={classes.menuButton} color="contrast" aria-label="Menu">
      <MenuIcon />
    </IconButton>
    <Typography type="title" color="inherit" className={classes.flex}>
      Title
    </Typography>
    {auth && (
      <Manager>
        <Target>
          <IconButton
            aria-owns={open ? 'menu-list' : null}
            aria-haspopup="true"
            onClick={this.handleMenu}
            color="contrast"
          >
            <AccountCircle />
          </IconButton>
        </Target>
        <Popper
          placement="top-right"
          eventsEnabled={open}
          className={classNames({ [classes.popperClose]: !open })}
        >
          <ClickAwayListener onClickAway={this.handleClose}>
            <Grow in={open} id="menu-list" style={{ transformOrigin: '0 0 0' }}>
              <Paper>
                <MenuList role="menu">
                  <MenuItem onClick={this.handleClose}>Profile</MenuItem>
                  <MenuItem onClick={this.handleClose}>My account</MenuItem>
                  <MenuItem onClick={this.handleClose}>Logout</MenuItem>
                </MenuList>
              </Paper>
            </Grow>
          </ClickAwayListener>
        </Popper>
      </Manager>
    )}
  </Toolbar>
</AppBar>
```

Here is a mashup of your two cited examples on [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/nkyj41qjmj).  It needs work and was only added here to illustrate react-popper as a possibility.